# Get Formatted Value of Cell in Excel

Tags: excel

How do you get the formatted value of a cell when using `=CONCATENATE(E1, " - " , D1)`?

`E1 = 08/21/2014 8:00 PM EST (Formatted value = 08/21)`

`D1 = Task Item 1`

Wanted output: = `08/21 - Task Item 1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `TEXT()`  function:
`TEXT(value, format_text)`
So if the value is 23.5 and you pass `=TEXT(A1, "$0.00")` it will return `$23.50`
Source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx

Comment: In this case =TEXT(E1, "MM/yy")

Comment: Right so using your example: A1 = 5/1/2014 (formatted as date) A2 =TEXT(a1, 'MM/YY') returns 05/14

Comment: Doesn't work in my case as date codes "MM" and "YY" depend on Excel locale (in Spanish, Japanese, Ukrainian its different, like "дд", "TT" etc, so they won't work in some Excel locales).

Answer (score 1):

Building on @mmmmmpie answer,

I would go one further an argue that `=TEXT(E1,CELL("format",E1))` is the better solution

Comment: Unfortunately CELL("format", ...) returns "G" for custom formats.

Comment: This doesn't work. At least in my usecase. The Cell format returns something like "C2" and the TEXT function than uses that as notation. Meaning that a value of E1 like 21, or 45, or -1232, etc. doesn't matter. Excel will display them all as "C2" instead of an actual numeric value.