# How to reference Value instead of formula in a formula using Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In [Microsoft Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) 2010/2013, I have five data columns as follows :

```
           | A  | B |  C   | D  |  E  |
          ------------------------------
  line 1   |  12|  7|  1.71|   5| 8.57|



C1: it's a formula ==> A1/B1, and it's formatted as two decimal places.
```

However, the formula of `E1` (which is `C1*D1`) gives 8.57 instead of 8.55, I figured out that Excel uses C1's formula instead of the displayed value, which is not my expectation!

So how can I enforce Excel to use the value(displayed) of a cell instead of its formula, to calculate another formula?

**Note:** I can get around by using the following formula in `E1`:

```
ROUND(C1,2)*D1
```

...but I want a solution which gets the displayed value directly without formatting the `C1` twice.

Comment: You can also do in C1 `=ROUND(A1/B1,2)`

Comment: actually I like scott's answer quite a bit on this one.  Round your results to what you are going to display.

Comment: You could also set the workbook to use "Precision as Displayed" if you can deal with the other side-effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is the actual answer to the question:-

```
=D1*VALUE(TEXT(C1,"#."&REPT(0,RIGHT(CELL("format",C1),1))))
```

i.e. use the CELL function to find out how many places the number is formatted to then create a format with this number of decimal places and use it in a TEXT function to get the number in C1 to the number of places it is displayed as.

Whether you would ever want to do this is of course another matter.

CELL has the drawback that if you change the formatting of the number in C1, it doesn't update until you recalculate the spreadsheet.

VALUE can be omitted because the multiplication will coerce the string "1.71" to a number:-

```
=D1*TEXT(C1,"#."&REPT(0,RIGHT(CELL("format",C1),1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, but it's quite a bit complicated, as it may be used by a beginner user, I prefer to round either in `C1`  as Scott mentioned or in `E1`. Thanks

Comment: Yes I agree that Scott's is a sensible approach.

Comment: Why use so complex expression when the `CELL("contents", address)` simply give the content value of cell as specified in other answer provided by Epsilon3 here ?!

Comment: Simply because cell("contents",address) (in spite of getting several upvotes) gives the exact opposite of what OP asked for - to be able somehow to use the value of the cell _as it appears when formatted_ rather than the actual contents of the cell. I was kind of taking devil's advocate here, because although it's possible it probably isn't a good way of going about things.

Answer (score 9):

This is the access to a cell's contents, since your original question asked how to access the value rather than the formula that generates the value:

```
=CELL("contents",$C$1)
```

Comment: Simple and so useful! note that the address does not need to be absolute, `=CELL("contents", C1)` is enough and better if we want to use same formula in a range of cells or a column..

Comment: OP asked this: So how can I enforce Excel to use the value(displayed) of a cell instead of its formula - they mean what you see when the cell is formatted rather than what's actually there.

Comment: Tom- 

Use the TEXT(value, format_text) function:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163526/get-formatted-value-of-cell-in-excel